# How to avoid resize figures with matplotlib when exporting to PDF?

Tags: python, pdf-generation, matplotlib, python-2.7

I'm using Python 2.7 and Matplotlib to generate a multiple chart report.

I want produce this report to be exported as a PDF document.
I want to set the size of each page (12 inches width x 18 inches height). I'm using the code below, but what I get is a document with a page size that depends on the size of my computer's screen (if I use my laptop, the height is smaller than if I use my desktop PC).

I want to fix the size of each PDF page.

Does anybody know how to achieve this?

```
pp = PdfPages('output/JobTitleReport.pdf')
fig = mpyplot.figure(figsize=(12,18))

# [...]

pp.savefig()
pp.close()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether this works for PDF export also, but you can try setting the figure resolution explicitly, e.g.

```
pp.savefig(dpi=100)
```

At least for PNG export this produces a predictable image size for a given figure size.

Comment: I've tested this previously, but this don't produces the result that I expect.
In fact, if you don't set the dpi size, the default value es dpi=80.
The rare thing is that the height of the page is proportional to the  height of the page to be visible at the first view of the document in the host computer (to avoid scroll down the page of the document)  .